# How to make an effect by partitions in Hive

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hadoop2

I'm using Hive on MRv2, and I'm trying to optimize hive queries.

The database assumes the purchase history of a convenience store. This database contains 6 tables(customers(1M rows), shops(1K rows), employees(5K rows), genres(30 rows), items(3.5K rows), purchase_histories(1G rows)), and I made query that retrieves sum of number purchased for each item, genre and customers' gender.

```
SELECT c.gender, 
       g.name, 
       i.name, 
       Sum(ph.num) 
FROM   purchase_histories ph 
       JOIN customers c 
         ON ( c.id = ph.cus_id 
              AND ph.dt < $var1
              AND ph.dt > $var2 ) 
       JOIN items i 
         ON ( i.id = ph.item_id ) 
       JOIN genres g 
         ON ( g.id = i.gen_id ) 
GROUP  BY c.gender, 
          g.name, 
          i.name;
```

I made partition purchase_histories(dt), items(gen_id) and customers(gender, byear).

I compared this database and no partition database(contains same tables) by above query. I input some kinds of values to $var1 and $var2 to make reference numbers of rows of purchase_histories become 10,000,000.

I measured the process time, and I found the no partition database is faster(or equal) than the other. I checked execution logs and I found that the mapper number of the partitioned database is about 10~30 but a not partitioned database is about 150. I don't think the many mappers is definitely good but 10~30 mappers are too small. So I thought that I have to check some configuration about map numbers or memory size. But I don't know which configure to change and my thought is correct.

The result of EXPLAIN are [no_partitions](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iC-PCPievfh89TLLMlho5RADxvHQdc04) and [partitioned](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15QP9CSKJuwX8HgKQ2ED1VVZ7uUVPKOqH). And execution logs are [exe_log_no_partition](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rjf_6BgXHheGUiVUfzke3n5ggc_IyfBY) and [exe_log_partitioned](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eK_oueGXKjaIK63K5OER3Mc67i1osSgh).

Thanks.

**Addition**

1, I saw EXPLAIN result of partitioned and thought that the number of mapper is calculated from below formula:

`(the table size 2619958583)/(mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=256000000)`

Is it wrong?

Comment: there is no reason for your query speed to improve. even if you have partitions, your reducers still receive the same amount of data they received before

Comment: I thought it would be quicker because Hive could cut the search range thanks to partitions. Is it wrong?

Comment: the mappers' work gets easier, that's right, but you got three joins, the main burden is on reducers here. besides you have put your `dt` (range) conditions inside `on` clause, I'm not sure how this query would be compiled: either reducers will check the condition or mappers will filter out the range. if the first one, then partitioning is meaningless here because reducers will still get all the table files

Comment: I would suggest replacing `FROM purchase_histories ph ON ( c.id = ph.cus_id AND ph.dt < $var1 AND ph.dt > $var2 )` with `FROM ( select num, cus_id, item_id from purchase_histories where dt < $var1 and dt > $var2 ) ph ON ( c.id = ph.cus_id )`. this will decrease the reducer input, i.e. your reducers will get the data range between var1 and var2 only

Comment: regarding items and customers, I don't see any point of partitioning these ones, as there is no range condition on `gen_id` or `gender` or `byear`

Comment: Thanks. I checked EXPLAIN result of my original query. In `Map Operator Tree` table scan for purchase_histories table has occurred and `Num rows` is 10,100,000, so I thought reducers received only filtered data.

Comment: And I executed the query `select ... from (select num, cus_id, item_id from purchase_histories where dt <= $var1 AND dt >= $var2) ph join customers c on (ph.cus_id = c.id) join items...`. I do not know why but the execution time is longer than my original query. The execution time has variations, so I'm retrying now.

Comment: I'm going to use partitions on customers and genres in other queries. So in this query, I don't use range condition on `gen_id` or `gender` or `byear`.

Comment: The execution time of the query which you suggested is nearly the same as my original query. Every time it runs, the difference in execution time is about 50 to 100 seconds. I measured it a number of times and compared it, but it may be the reason why I felt late after setting partitions.

Comment: i see. how large is the [var1 var2] range that you're processing? maybe it is nearly as large as the table itself. in common, joining pre-selected dataset is quicker than joining the whole table and specifying partitions in "where" clause. Not sure about "On" clause though, but the concept is same, i guess

Comment: The range of [var1 var2] is 101,000,000. And purchase_histories table has 1,000,000,000 rows. Should I use view?

Comment: view doesn't really matter since it is still going to run the underlying query whenever you select something from it. by the way, in case if my version's and original version's runtimes are nearly the same, it implies that both queries are compiled into the same set of map-reduce jobs i.e. original query already makes use of date partitions

Comment: if you wonder about the number of mappers, then obviously unpartitioned table would require many more mappers than partitioned because mappers need to process all table files. however there will be no difference between runtimes of partitioned and unpartitioned table queries, AS LONG AS hadoop will be able to assign enough number of mappers for unpartitioned table processing. If there were other hadoop jobs running together with your query, then hadoop probably wouldn't be able to assign 150 mappers to it, which means it would run slower than on partitioned one

Comment: I see. In the query plan in my question, there are differences between partitioned and no partitioned. So I thought both queries are compiled into a different set of mapreduce job. So it is natural that the number of mappers is small in partitioned case.

Comment: As I wrote in addition. 1, the number of mapper in partitioned case seems reasonable. I wonder if it is better to recalibrate..